# iOS: OpenEers doesn't work

Tags: ios, openears

I am trying to use OpenEars speech recognition kit, but doesn't work on my iPhone 3GS. I've written all code snippets provided by their tutorial, but nothing happens while speaking. Here's my code:

```
LanguageModelGenerator *lmGenerator = [[LanguageModelGenerator alloc] init];

NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"EAT", @"DRINK", @"SLOW", @"GO", nil];
NSString *name = @"NameIWantForMyLanguageModelFiles";
NSError *err = [lmGenerator generateLanguageModelFromArray:words withFilesNamed:name forAcousticModelAtPath:[AcousticModel pathToModel:@"AcousticModelEnglish"]]; // Change "AcousticModelEnglish" to "AcousticModelSpanish" to create a Spanish language model instead of an English one.


NSDictionary *languageGeneratorResults = nil;

NSString *lmPath = nil;
NSString *dicPath = nil;

if([err code] == noErr) {

    languageGeneratorResults = [err userInfo];

    lmPath = [languageGeneratorResults objectForKey:@"LMPath"];
    dicPath = [languageGeneratorResults objectForKey:@"DictionaryPath"];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
}



[self.openEarsEventsObserver setDelegate:self];

[self.pocketsphinxController startListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath:lmPath dictionaryAtPath:dicPath acousticModelAtPath:[AcousticModel pathToModel:@"AcousticModelEnglish"] languageModelIsJSGF:NO];
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, OpenEars developer here. I really prefer to give assistance at the OpenEars forums since the SO format isn't oriented around troubleshooting, but do you have any OpenEarsEventsObserver callbacks in this view controller? Check out the "Using OpenEarsEventsObserver" part of the tutorial (it's the last step). You can also troubleshoot by seeing if the sample app works on your phone and then looking at the differences between the projects.

Comment: From where can I get the sample app?

Comment: It's in the OpenEars distribution you downloaded, in the root level of the main directory.